# Java Runtime Environment HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Error

Tags: java, windows, registry, runtime, environment

I was trying to get rid of older versions of Java (since I still had 1.6 and I also had 1.7) on my Windows XP machine. Well uninstalling 1.6 I got an error about Java Runtime Environment. When I try and start up Java Control Panel it gives me this error:

> The system cannot find the registry key specified:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7.0_05

I've tried to reinstall Java but that does nothing. And I can't fully remove Java because whenever I try it gives me an error saying there was an error in the installation. To be specific:

> Fatal error during installation.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?  It keeps me from doing a lot which is frustrating.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of java installed?

Comment: You might try something from this list (http://download.cnet.com/windows/uninstallers/) but I can't vouch for what they will do. They should, at least, get you to a point that will allow you to reinstall 1.7 if you wish.

Comment: Java is both a programming environment and a runtime environment. This question is about a problem uninstalling the runtime environment, so it is more of a question about using Java than a programming question. I recommend moving it to superuser.stackexachange.com

Comment: oh god registry cleaners

Comment: I've only got 1.7.5 installed atm. I removed 1.6. Not sure why it's giving me this problem. Didn't do it when I removed 1.5 and updated to 1.6 ages ago. :\

Comment: Alright.  Scary answer inbound

Answer (score 7):

**Author's note:** This answer was written to address installations of Java, major versions 6 and 7. It may or may not work with versions of java that are newer or older, but it probably won't hurt to try.  If you follow these instructions for a major version not listed, please comment whether you were successful or not.

---

1. Read all of the directions twice.  This solution details a manual uninstall of java by modifying the windows registry.  If you do not follow the directions, you can cause permanent damage to your windows installation and will need serious firepower to get it working correctly again.  If you do not understand the risks, ask someone for help.
2. If you have any registry cleaners, get rid of them.  This is probably their fault.  I've never met one I liked and wouldn't let one touch my registry with a 10 foot read only pole.
3. If you're using a laptop, connect to a charger.  If you have children, make them walk the dog.  Find a quiet secluded place and hole yourself up in it with zero distractions for about 15 minutes.
4. Make a backup of the registry key "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft", save it somewhere safe.
5. Delete exactly the following and only exactly the following registry key and all of its subkeys: "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft".  After you are done with this step, java is dead.  Do not try to run any java programs at this stage, it almost certainly won't work.
6. Open "C:\Program Files" (and, if you're on a 64 bit machine, "C:\Program Files (x86)").  If you see folders called Java, rename them to "Java_".  If you installed java to a nonstandard location, navigate to it and add an underscore to its name.
7. Download and install the latest version.  The installation should complete with no issues.  It should also overwrite any leftover chunks of the old installation that are left.
8. (optional) Uninstall java again.  The uninstallation should go smoothly and it should properly dispose of any leftover resources installed by the broken installation.  Reinstall when the uninstall is complete.  Since you are installing the same version you just removed, this probably isn't necessary.

Final note: I have performed this surgery many times on other people's computers using teamviewer, and it has never gone wrong.  In the social circles where I hang out, we call it a javaectomy.  For reference, I hang out on IRC and help people with issues with minecraft.  We think we have seen every possible java issue.  This one is fairly common and caused by some combination of many concurrent java versions, registry cleaners, and interrupted or failed updates.  Once you are done and have verified that the reinstallation has gone smoothly and without issues, you can remove your saved registry keys and delete the renamed java folders from "program files" and "program files (x86)" (remember to delete only the ones with an appended underscore, the one called Java was added by the reinstall and should be left as is.

Disaster recovery: In the unlikely event that something goes wrong, restore the renamed java folders and patch the registry keys with your backup to revert to the original (partially broken) state.

Comment: so, just to make sure, do you delete the registry key right after you back it up or after you reinstall version 7 update 5?

Comment: Ok so I've done that, and when I get to 7 (I followed each step) I still get it claiming it's installed

Comment: you should visit me on irc.  http://webchat.esper.net/?nick=TheGodEmperor&channels=#xyzzy  <- click

Comment: I got it done :P reinstalled and all fix. Damn I wish Sun (Oracle, whatever) would have their newer versions properly remove old ones. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: So it worked correctly?  OK.  let this never be spoken of again.  Also, don't seek to take fixes like this upon yourself unless professionally advised.

Comment: This sounds scriptable - if a little hairy. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Over the years since I made this post, it has become clear to me that one of the primary causes of broken installations like this is that java's updater will continue to run *without administrative privileges* if you respond "NO" to the UAC prompt it generates, which will result in a horrible chimera of pain and suffering as the installer applies all of the changes that don't require administrative privileges, and skips all of the ones that do.  I'm not sure if this problem has been fixed in newer versions, and its behavior varies between windows versions due to differing default permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I must congratulate Wug for his/her contribution in removing old Java residues. I tried every Uninstaller available (free) to no avail. Except for a Caveat, everything Wug suggested works. The only Caveat is that after #6 (renaming Java Folder in Program Files), you must use the Windows Uninstaller. Why? Because if you try to install the downloaded Java, it will warn you that you already have Java installed. Run the uninstaller from the Add or Remove Programs (Control Panel). It will give you an error that it couldn't find the uninstaller and then it will remove the Java reference from the Add/Remove Programs. Then do installation of the downloaded Java file and you are free of the old Java references.

GREAT JOB, WUG!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while updating `Java`  on my machine to `1.8`. I had opted for uninstall of existing version while the installation and it did something to the registry keys.This fix worked to me .

> 1. Uninstall all versions of JDK and JRE from your machine.
> 2. Restart it.
> 3. Install 1.7 JDK.
> 4. Then install whatever JDK you want.